# Meaning of 上がりくる

Tags: meaning, interpretation

> ドアを開ける時ノブが**上がりきっていたら**誰かが部屋に入った可能性がある

This part is from Death Note.

Is this musu stem(連用形) + きって (te form of くる)?
If so, how is it different from 上がってきって?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb you're seeing is 上がり切る【きる】, not 上がり来る【くる】. (The te-form of 来る is きて, not きって.) 切る in a compound verb often means "thoroughly" or "fully". (食べ切る, 買い切る, 読み切る, ...)

> ノブが上がりきっていたら
>   if the doorknob has fully moved up, ...